# Name of the monotone-like property "$f(x)\geq f(x\wedge y)$ implies $f(x\vee y)\geq f(x)$" on a lattice

Tags: terminology, lattice-orders, monotone-functions

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a lattice. There is a function $f$ that has the following property.

> $f(x)\geq f(x\wedge y)$ implies $f(x\vee y)\geq f(x)$

where strict inequality on the left-hand side implies strict inequality on the right-hand.

At a first glance, the property looks like some type of monotonicity as $f$ should be increasing in its arguments.. but it is more general than the monotonicity.

Anyone happens to know the name of this property?

Answer (score 2):

Let me rewrite the question here:

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a lattice. There is a function $f$ that has the following properties:

1. $f(x)\geq f(x\wedge y)$ implies $f(x\vee y)\geq f(x)$,
2. strict inequality on the left-hand side implies strict inequality on the right-hand side.

Claim I. A function $f$ satisfies Condition 1. if and only if $f$ is a **monotone function**.
Claim II.  A function $f$ satisfies both 1. and 2. if and only if $f$ is a **constant function**.

Reasoning for Claim 1.
Assume that $f$ satisfies the implication in Condition 1.
We have
$$\begin{array}{rll}
y\geq x&\to x=x\wedge y&\\
&\to f(x)=f(x\wedge y)&\textrm{($f$ is a function)}\\
&\to f(x\vee y)\geq f(x)&\textrm{(Condition 1.)}\\
&\to f(y)\geq f(x)&\textrm{($x\vee y =y$)}.
\end{array}
$$
This shows that $y\geq x$ implies $f(y)\geq f(x)$.
Conversely, if $f$ is any monotone function with domain $X$,
then since $x\vee y\geq x$ we have $f(x\vee y)\geq f(x)$.
This shows that the conclusion of the implication in
Condition 1. always holds
for monotone functions.

Reasoning for Claim 2.
To prove that a function $f$ satisfying
Conditions 1. and 2. is constant, it suffices to prove that
$f(x)=f(y)$ whenever $x,y\in X$ are comparable.
(Justification: Suppose that we have shown that $f(x)=f(y)$ when $x$ and $y$
are comparable. Given arbitrary $u, v\in X$, both $u$ and $v$
are comparable with $u\wedge v$, so  $f(u) = f(u\wedge v) = f(v)$, implying that $f$ is constant.) 
We argue by contradiction. Assume that $f$ satisfies Conditions 1. and 2. but that $X$ contains $x\geq y$
for which $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Necessarily $x>y$. By Condition 1., $f$ is monotone, so we must have $f(x)>f(y)\;\;(=f(x\wedge y))$.
Applying Conditions 1.+2. to $f(x)>f(x\wedge y)$, we must have $f(x\vee y)>f(x)$. But $x=x\vee y$, so this reduces to $f(x)>f(x)$, which is false.  This contradiction proves Claim 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like the two claims are mainly driven by the case $y\geq x$. If I impose the property 1 to be hold true only for $y\ngeq x$,  would there be a lot of changes to the answer? My guess is that f should monotonically increase or decrease.